# Under xx years of age vs. less than xx-year-old

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, american-english, word-difference

In written English, which way is a better or correct way to say? Or any difference?

1. Participants are less than 40-year-old.
2. Participants are under 40 years of age.
3. Participants are younger than 40-year-old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"40-year-old" is often used as a noun, as in "a 40-year-old", so the first and last are awkward. The second is correct and could also be

> Participants are under 40 years old.

Comment: Also, if it's obvious we are talking about age, that version can be shortened even further: _Participants are under 40._  A couple examples: _Shivery .. estimates about seventy-five percent of their customers are [under 40](http://www.oregonlive.com/pacific-northwest-news/index.ssf/2017/07/post_272.html)._ Also: _In China, the average age of new-car buyers hovers around 34. Thirty-eight percent of all new luxury car buyers there are [under 40](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2017-06-28/rolls-royce-drivers-are-a-lot-younger-than-you-think)_.

Answer (score 1):

> Participants are less than 40.
>   Participants are younger than 40.

This would probably be how I would say it.

Both of "less than 40-year-old" and "younger than 40-year-old" are incorrect. If you want to retain the "years old" concept, you would just say "less/younger than 40". "Participants are under 40 years of age." is correct, but clunky - I would say "Participants are under 40 years old." instead.

Dashes ("40-year-old") are generally only used as a "compound" noun when identifying a person - "I have two children, a 3-year-old and a 5-year-old."